# what is the difference between efficient learning and effective learning?

Tags: meaning

I have trouble understanding the difference in the meaning of "effective" and "efficient". 
what is the difference between "efficient learning" and "effective learning"?

Comment: Have you looked up both *efficient* and *effective* in the dictionary? Please say what about the definitions you found confusing.

Comment: Yes, I did look up in the dictionary. Is it right to say that "efficiency" deals more with the process and what we do while we are doing an activity and "effective" deals more with the outcome?

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with that characterization.

Answer (score 2):

Effective learning is learning that works well. Efficient learning is learning that uses minimal resources will still achieving good results. Another way of saying it is that the results to resources ratio is good.